# Stretched OpenGL content after modal view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller

I'm testing out an OpenGL concept, so my app consists of a window with an OpenGL view and nothing else.

I'm experience a problem where, after a UIViewController is presented modally, the content in the OpenGL view is stretched (doubled?) vertically.

The app is restricted to landscape-right, and I'm just drawing cubes at the moment to test this.

Another weird thing is that when I had tested this a while back (on iOS 5 or 6), the Game Center leaderboards view controller would cause this to happen. Now it doesn't - it can be shown and dismissed without affecting the underlying OpenGL view - however any of my own UIViewControllers that I show and dismiss cause the problem to appear.

I can potentially deal with it by tracking when a view controller is shown and then scaling the OpenGL content accordingly, but this seems very hacky - it seems to me that the content should not start stretching at all.

Edit: So I logged the frames of the containing view and the OpenGL view, and this is what I got:

```
Frame before (this view):    {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
Frame before (glview):       {{0, 0}, {568, 320}}
Frame after (this view):     {{0, 0}, {568, 320}}
Frame after (glview):        {{0, 0}, {568, 320}}
```

So you can see that the width and the height of the container view flips. I still have no idea how to fix this, though - setting the frame of both of the views again didn't work, and I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'm not sure why the frame was flipping its width and height, but I fixed it, yay!

When setting up the GL view (which was done on viewWillAppear, hence the problem starting when another view controller was shown and dismissed), the camera was set up using the frame of the container view to set the aspect ratio, as follows: `CGSize layerSize = self.view.layer.frame.size;`

This view is the one that flipped its width and height, so when the GL view was set up again, the aspect ratio caused the contents to be stretched. Since I know my GL view is the full width and height of the screen at all times, I fixed it by using the screen bounds to set up the camera/aspect ratio: `CGSize layerSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;`

And now it works perfectly!